# SELECT inside INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table (temp_value) VALUES ( SELECT source_value FROM the_table WHERE condition_value = some_value ) WHERE temp_condition = some_value_condition
```

Do you guys know a way of doing this?

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Never mind, I just had a _lapsus brutus_ and was trying to use `INSERT INTO` instead of UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need the values keyword

```
INSERT INTO mytable( aa,bb,cc )
SELECT a,b,c FROM xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO temp_table (temp_value)  SELECT source_value FROM the_table WHERE condition_value = some_value  And temp_condition = some_value_condition
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some like this basic structure

```
INSERT INTO temp_table (Value1,Value2,Value3) 
SELECT field1, field2, field3 
FROM the_table 
WHERE condition_value = some_value
```

Remember have the same number of fields in your `INSERT INTO` and your `SELECT`.